# Send email from VB.Net without SMTP Gateway

Tags: vb.net, smtp, gmail, sendmail

I am looking for an alternative to using smtp.gmail.com as they have disabled SMTP relay at my work place. And they are adamant they will not make any exceptions.

I have written an extensive application in VB.net which captures a boat load of requirements from the user. At the end there is obviously a button to send all the captured data to some recipients. My code is as follows :

```
Private Sub btnEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEmail.Click
    email.From = New MailAddress("kuldip.mond123@gmail.com", "Kuldip Mond")
    email.Subject = "SAP Order Prerequisite Form"
    email.Body = "Message Text as Body of email."
    email.IsBodyHtml = True
    email.To.Add("kmond@mycompany.com")
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("kmond@mycompany.com", "*********")
    smtp.Send(email)
    MsgBox("Email Sent")
End Sub
```

I have considered and read up on SMTP Client with gmail Apps script etc but somewhere sometime sooner or later they all boil down to using a smtp.gmail.com

Would appreciate any guidence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have IT admins that care enough to disable SMTP relay, they will be able to give you the connection info to their own SMTP server you can use to send email from your application.

Comment: I understand, I don't have IT Admin, but they will not/can not allow me to use any SMTP from any server as all the servers are production servers and they are owned by various depts and they won't share in case of problems. Secondly, they required "Static IP Address on a Server" so i seem to be stomped at every point. So the only way forward is to find a work round myself. Grrrrr

Comment: As far as workarounds, what about a web script that generates the email? Host it on a free server where SMTP isn't blocked and have your application pass the info to it?

Comment: Indeed, thats EXACTLY where all my investigation have led me two. Being from a web design backgroud - I think I am going communicate all the mail details to a PHP script or web script on a company web location and then send. My ownly issue is that we have Sharepoint at work so I am not entirely sure if its possible within Sharepoint. I will keep digging... ;-|

Answer (score -1):

Will an SMTP gateway be available when the application is published? If so, there are a number of local SMTP host solutions for development environments.

I am in the same situation with my IT team myself (no SMTP for dev, but we have access for UAT and Live), and I use the SMTP4Dev (https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) application happily.

If you point to the application as your SMTP server, any e-mails sent out using it will be caught by the application and be readable by you.

Comment: No, actually development or production. Work categorically do NOT allow sending of email via SMTP gateway. I can understand that they don't wont mass email of any kind being sent. Thxs